# Oozie on HDInsight: OozieServerStatus

Tags: oozie, azure-hdinsight, hortonworks-data-platform

Oozie server is started without any exceptions. While trying to get the status using below command, it is giving 404 error.

```
$clusterUriStatus = "https://$clusterName.azurehdinsight.net:443/oozie/v2/admin/status" 
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $clusterUriStatus -Credential $creds -OutVariable $OozieServerStatus
```

Error Message from Server:

> Invoke-RestMethod : HTTP Status 404 - /oozie/v2/admin/status
>   type Status report
>   message /oozie/v2/admin/status
>   description The requested resource is not available.
>   Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
>   At line:1 char:13
>   + $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $clusterUriStatus -Credential $cr ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc
>      eption
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an HDInsight 2.1 cluster try the v1 endpoint:

```
https://$clusterName.azurehdinsight.net:443/oozie/v1/admin/status
```

The v2 endpoint should work for HDInsight 3.0, the v1 endpoint should be present for 2.1 and 3.0.